# Custom Editor for TFS 2010 Work Items possible via SDK

Tags: api, tfs, sdk

I m fairly new to working with the TFS SDK and & was wondering whether it's possible to use/write a custom editor 'control' for the work item text editor.. in order to provide more powerful editing capabilities (images, tables etc).

Does anyone know whether this is possible without breaking the rules of physics and/or whether there are already 3rd party solutions out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any 3rd party tools to JUST do that, I am quite fond of [Telerik TFS Work Item Manager](http://www.telerik.com/team-productivity-tools/products/tfsmanager-and-tfsdashboard.aspx) though.

It is definitely possible to include a custom control on your work item form essentially displaying images. Here is the offical MSDN for [Work Item Tracking Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286959.aspx). There are some ready-made custom controls on Codeplex: [TFS Work Item Tracking Custom Controls](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/).

Lastly a good discussion: [Display Image in work item form for TFS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/a52c665a-76aa-4951-b979-9164cf856edb). (About really having rich-text within the work items like tables etc. I couldn't find anything)

Comment: The extensibility model of TFS 2010 does not allow to replace the default work item form with your own implementation. The suggestions by moontear are the only options you have to create other experiences.